# Jquery Draggable Element Intersect

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, draggable, intersection

I wanna make  if Dragged element intersect any draggable elements  dragged items revert old position. Any Idea About it?

```
                $( "#MainContents div[name=draggable]" ).each(function() {
$( this ).draggable({containment: 'parent',
  scrollSpeed: 1000,
  cursor: "crosshair",
   scroll:true,
 disabled: DragDropState,
stop: function(event, ui) {
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        var parentPosition=$(this).parent().position();
        var CalculatedTop=Stoppos.top-parentPosition.top;
        var CalculatedLeft=Stoppos.left-parentPosition.left;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you asking when a dragged element is dropped on another draggable element you want the element that was just dropped to go back where it originally was?

Comment: Yes it is. When Element Dropped to other draggable element. it will just go back.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to record where it came from on dragging start and then check for an overlay on dragging stop.  check out this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h34dq/)

in a nutshell, extend your draggable options array to include start, record the top/left position in a data object, then on stop, check other draggable items in the DOM and call a revert function if anything matches.

ex:

```
$( this ).draggable({
start: function() {
  var div = $(this);
        div.data('top', div.css('top'));
        div.data('left', div.css('left'));
},
containment: 'parent',
  scrollSpeed: 1000,
  cursor: "crosshair",
   scroll:true,
 disabled: DragDropState,
stop: function(event, ui) {
        var draggables = $('.ui-draggable');
        var div = $(this);
        var goHome = function () {
            div.css('left', div.data('left'));
            div.css('top', div.data('top'));
        };

        draggables.not(div).each(function () {
            var curr = $(this);
            var currPos = curr.position();
            var divPos = div.position();
            if (divPos.left >= currPos.left && divPos.left <= (currPos.left + curr.width())) {
                if (divPos.top >= currPos.top && divPos.top <= (currPos.top + curr.height())) {
                    goHome();
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

i'm pretty sure something like this is what you're looking to do.  btw, from here you can animate the revert function so it gracefully goes back where it was last at.

Comment: Thanks ,  It is not catch actually but You gave me idea. I was thinking. Maybe there is an function return true or false like intersect function  in java.